# React Native: prevent ScrollView from resetting on every re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, uiscrollview, react-native-scrollview

I have a component in my React Native app that contains a `<ScrollView>`. This component also receives a prop `this.props.a` that gets updated every 60s. So every 60s the component gets re-rendered, including the ScrollView, which makes it scroll back to the top. Is there a way to prevent the re-rendering of the ScrollView when its parent component gets passed a new prop?